# BASH: can't use variable inside function

Tags: bash, function, variables

In my function I defined a Variable: CHECKRESULT:

```
function checkport {
if nc -zv -w3 $1 $2 <<< '' &> /dev/null
then
    echo -e "TCP-Port $1/$2 is open"
    CHECKRESULT="ok"
else
    echo -e "TCP-Port $1/$2 is closed" 
    CHECKRESULT="error"
fi
}
```

Later in the script I have a if-statement which uses the CHECKRESULT variable:

```
if ssh -q $host-- "$(declare -f checkport); checkport $someotherhost ${Ports[$i]} &> /dev/null" && [ "$CHECKRESULT" == "ok" ]
```

Unfortunattely, the $CHECKRESULT variable seems to always be "ok". Even if my function fails, the variable won't be updated with "error".

I belive this is because the function is executed via ssh on a remote host and the local machine won't get the results in the variable defined.

Do i need to source the variable? Or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The function is running on the remote system, so that's where the variable is being defined. But you're testing it on the local system, which can't see the remote value. It'd probably be better to have the function print just result, capture that with `CHECKRESULT =$(ssh ...)`, then testing *that*. BTW, I also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid accidental conflicts with the many all-caps names with special meanings or functions. I'd also avoid `echo -e` and the `function` keyword, since they're nonstandard and will fail on some shells.

Comment: If you want to keep the `echo` or expect that you will one day print other information on stdout, I suggest that you write the value of the variable to a file and read it from this file from your local host.

Answer (score 1):

> I belive this is because the function is executed via ssh on a remote
> host and the local machine won't get the results in the variable
> defined.

Correct.

> Do i need to source the variable?

No.

> Or how can I solve this problem?

This is just a symptom of a more general problem with the code. Regardless of calling it via ssh or not, avoid using global variables to share information between functions and the calling code as that breaks encapsulation. Write `checkport` as:

```
checkport() {
    local state=closed result=1

    if nc -zv -w3 "$1" "$2" <<< '' &> /dev/null
    then
        state=open
        result=0
    fi

    printf 'TCP-Port %s/%s is %s\n' "$1" "$2" "$state"
    return "$result"
}
```

or, if you don't want to use an exit status for some reason, then:

```
checkport() {
    local state=closed result=error

    if nc -zv -w3 "$1" "$2" <<< '' &> /dev/null
    then
        state=open
        result=ok
    fi

    printf 'TCP-Port %s/%s is %s\n' "$1" "$2" "$state" >&2
    printf '%s\n' "$result"
}
```

or:

```
    printf 'TCP-Port %s/%s is %s\n' "$1" "$2" "$state"
    printf '%s\n' "$result" >&2
```

or:

```
    printf 'TCP-Port %s/%s is %s\n' "$1" "$2" "$state"
    printf '%s\n' "$result"
```

or similar (whichever is most appropriate for your needs - redirecting the state or result to stderr or printing both to stdout or stderr) and then write your calling code to use that, e.g. if you use the first script above that uses an exit status (the most likely to be what you should use given what I see so far in your code):

```
if state=$(checkport "$someotherhost" "${Ports[$i]}"); then
    do success stuff
else
    do failure stuff
fi
printf 'checkport output "%s"\n' "$state"
```

As an added bonus that will solve your current problem since you no longer have a global variable being set on one machine inside the function and attempting to be read by another machine outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function always **exits** with 0 meaning success:

```
function checkport {
if nc -zv -w3 $1 $2 <<< '' &> /dev/null
then
    echo -e "TCP-Port $1/$2 is open"
    CHECKRESULT="ok"
else
    echo -e "TCP-Port $1/$2 is closed" 
    CHECKRESULT="error"
    # missing return 1
fi
 # always returns 0 by default on end of function
}
```

Do you need your function to print anything? Just:

```
if ssh -q $host -- nc -zv -w3 $1 $2 <<<'' &> /dev/null; then
   CHECKRESULT="ok"
else
   CHECKRESULT="error"
fi
```

If you want your function, make your function exit with failure - add missing `return 1` on error path.